# What is Angular ng module? How can we use it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

angular.js create an internal module named 'ng' at angular init steps. And 'ng' is documented as core module([here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng)). We know Angular published some services/factories, filters, directives to module 'ng'.

But what's the function of module 'ng'? How and where can we use 'ng' at our Angular app? Would you give an simple example for the usage of 'ng'?

Comment: You have the uses in the `ng` module documentation you linked. If you click any function, it shows examples.

Comment: Thanks sailens! I can use angular.module() to create an external module. And I just confuse about the relationship of internal 'ng' module and external module.

Comment: short answer is it's the main module that your modules are extending. Since you don't do anything with modules other than declare them why would you need to do anything with `ng`?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need anything special to do.

This is the core module. Look at it as internal module which is always here.

All those (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng) Services and directives can be used directly.

angular. functions are just functions on the global object angular. $ prefixed services can be injected as usual.

Comment: Yes, we don't need to do anything for internal 'ng' module. Just confused about external self-defined module by angular.module() and internal 'ng' module.

Comment: angular.module(name, [dependencies]) is method for creating own modules. Your application is ussualy created from dozen of your and dozen of 3rd party modules.

Comment: For example look at here - https://bitbucket.org/angular_cz/beerapp-codio/src/b5ace5e9e4010a1fd8f4190c281eb7fcbe47c9b6/src/app/?at=master app.js creates main module which depends on modules in  subdirs.